# C# ASP.NET Core Web API will not serve requests to my api controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

At a bit of a loss here. Writing an ASP.NET Core Web API as a sort of backend for frontend, and cannot seem to get my API routes to register / work. When I attempt to hit the endpoint it is almost as if it is not treated as a controller route. The project is targeting .NET 7.

`program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using AppServices.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddDataProtection();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.Map("", client =>
{
    var clientPath = Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Client/dist");

    StaticFileOptions clientAppDist = new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(clientPath)
    };

    client.UseSpaStaticFiles(clientAppDist);

    client.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = clientAppDist;
    });
});

app.UseAuth();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Controller in question:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BFF.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet(Name = "test")]
        public string GetTest()
        {
            return "test12345";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This means the url is regard as the staticfile middleware instead of the api route. What happened if you remove that middleware.

Comment: @BrandoZhang weirdly enough it still serves the SPA, which it shoudln't as it should then look for files in wwwroot instead of the path I specified, however it doesn't seem to. I should probably look into that a little more

Answer (score 0):

the issue starts here:

```
app.Map("", client =>{ }
```

instead of this whole Map block, just do:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Client/dist")),RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"});
```